# Include extra (custom) info to awstats_misc_tracker.js in AWSTats

Tags: awstats

How can I include extra info to the awstats_misc_tracker.js. I want to add logged user name to be tracked on AWStats. I can include the info to the javascript itself, but what I want know is how to configure AWstats to track and catalog that new information.

Thanks in advance,

Aldo

Answer (score 0):

not really an answer to your question but you can give piwik a try, we switched from awstats to piwik and it does a good job.

Cheers 
Izac